# MYSQL, Insert/Update, if else statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP with mysqli and in this example I'm trying to update the price if the `username` and `lastname` exists in the database, else I want to insert a new user. Why is this not working?

```
IF (SELECT name,lastname FROM peoplePrice WHERE name='gus' AND lastname='lw') THEN
    UPDATE peoplePrice SET price='20' WHERE name='gus' AND lastname='lw';
ELSE
    INSERT INTO peoplePrice (name,lastname,price) 
    VALUES ('nisse','johansson','20');
END IF;
```

Comment: `SELECT` returns rows.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists

Comment: try with SELECT COUNT(*) instead

Comment: Are you just inserting a random user, or should `name` and `lastname` match the ones used in the `SELECT`?

Comment: you can do the condition checking in php, and then execute the related queries.

Comment: @wolfsgang This would not be a good idea. If different instances of the script run in parallel, there could be raising conditions resulting in multiple attempts to create rows for the same person.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't offer the kind of conditional logic you're using except in stored procedures. You should investigate INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to do what you're trying to do. Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html